# Horror Episode #6: Lord of the Fries

Tags: logical-deduction, mystery

An amusement park chef named Maxwell was heading into the kitchen to clean up and shut down after another successful dinner service. He has a bit of grievance over his head as so do the other chefs, since there was a chef named Samuel that has gone missing for about 2 days. As he was cleaning the kitchen, he noticed an oil fryer that seemed to be bubbling for the last couple days, a timeline strangely close to how long Samuel was gone. Using an aluminum ladle, Maxwell dug in to the fryer only to jump back in absolute terror as a burned head was surfaced.

Forensic experts clarified that it was Samuel's head.

The chefs were frightened that a killer was afoot in their troupe. The chefs were asked to talk about what they were doing on the night of the death. Due to the group chat they have with each other on their cell phones, the chefs agreed that this would be easy.

Nathaniel: I was asked to go clean up the restaurant floors outside the kitchen when I heard a horrifying scream come from the kitchen. When I ran inside, I saw Evan making the call on his phone to tell everyone that someone kidnapped Samuel.

Tina: I had the day off and was woken up from a light sleep when I got the call.

Evan: As Nathaniel said, I was calling everyone about the kidnapping. I have bad wounds on my back and neck that still hurt from trying to fight off the kidnapper. I couldn't very well see who it was though.

Valerie: I, like Tina, had the day off, though I didn't want to stay home due to how much I loved work. I was having fun on the Ferris wheel when I got the call.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the kidnapper introduced himself to Samuel as the brother of an anonymous chef he fell for, but his sexual preference was unknown by the other chefs. Still, the police managed to arrest the culprit chef. Can you tell whodunit?

> It seems like you all are overthinking it. Think about the fact that it was the whole park's closing time, as in, when the chefs of this amusement park were cleaning. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough with this fact, but now it should be simple

Comment: Too many pronouns in that last paragraph. Who fell for the anonymous chef, The kidnapper or Samuel? Whose sexual preference, the kidnapper or the anonymous chef?

Comment: Samuel fell for the anonymous chef, though it actually doesn't matter who fell for the chef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab

> Valerie

because

> according to the hint, it was past closing, so how was she on the ferris wheel at the time?

but

> even with the hint, I don't think that is nearly enough conclusive evidence.  Just guessing this might be what OP was going for.

Comment: Ack, didn't see this one before I made my edit. I agree with you entirely.

Answer (score 6):

I can't escape the conclusion that

> I must be guilty.

That would be because

> somehow I know how the kidnapper introduced himself, even though none of the cooks ever mentioned it (and couldn't very well have done so "offscreen" either, without admitting to having noticed the kidnapper ahead of time). Also Samuel, being inconveniently kidnapped and/or dead at the time, would have been unable to tell me, at least unless I was in on the crime.

Comment: Oh dear...      uhhhhh.....

Answer (score 1):

The murderer is

> Maxwell

Reasoning:

> Maxwell is described as an amusement park chef who finds Samuel's head. However, I believe that he may be a chef for a rival business at the amusement park since he is (assumption here) not in the same group chat as the rest of the chefs.

This isn't a particularly serious answer (doesn't even follow the logical-deduction tag), but I'm mostly hoping to point out the oddity that I've mentioned.

Comment: Good try, but incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was

> Evan

Because

> The kidnapping attempt on Evan happened two days prior (Samuel had been missing for that long). It’s weird that he would wait two days before calling everybody to tell them there was a problem if that was the case.

Comment: Your answer mentions a name that doesn't appear anywhere in the question.

Comment: I could be wrong but my understanding was that according to Evan(I think you meant Evan not Eric), the kidnapper came in while him and Samuel were in the kitchen (two days ago). Evan was attacked, Samuel was kidnapped, Evan called everyone to let them know what happened(he called right after it happened). Then two days later (present time) Samuel's head is found.

Comment: Gabbo is right. The call happened on the night of the murder

Answer (score 0):

New Guess:

> Let's try Valerie based off the new hint. If the chef's are cleaning, and thus closing, why would the ferris wheel be open and operational? Seems like her story is thus false.

---

I'll go with

> Evan

Because

> - He was the only chef in the kitchen with Samuel.
>  - Also, you mentioned "the kidnapper introduced **himself** to Samuel", which would eliminate the female chefs from consideration.
>  - Evan also has wounds that could have actually been from scraping with Samuel.
>  - Nathaniel was outside.

Issues and points of confusion:

> - Where is Maxwell's alibi?
>  - Why would Evan call everyone of the chefs and not the cops or something?
>  - How would they have not noticed a fryer being left on for two days (or if Maxwell did notice, he's either the killer or just very negligent)? They wouldn't have used that fryer in that time? Who was supposed to clean the kitchen the last two nights!?
>  - How would the head end up in the fryer, particularly with the blood and the body. Which, where did the body go? Especially in such a short time?

Here's a fun extra idea:

> Maybe it was two chefs, and it was done in cahoots. Let's say Evan and Valerie are siblings. (I chose her because I consider her behavior odd, and she mentioned loving work in the past tense. Besides, she wasn't working but was still there?). Maybe Samuel was hitting on Valerie, and neither she nor her brother liked that. So, they "kidnapped" Samuel, and Valerie made off with the body while Samuel stuck around and made the calls etc.

Comment: No. At the end of the puzzle it says that the kidnapper is the brother of the mastermind chef behind it all

Answer (score 0):

I think it was

> Evan

Because

> He had wounds on his back and neck, even though he claims that he was fighting the "kidnapper". Also he is the only one who would have been able to put Samuel in the fryer before anyone else went into the kitchen that night.

Comment: Good thought but incorrect